# Calculate float at compile-time using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to this whole Template Metaprogramming in C++ mess and I simply can't get this right.

The scenario:
For example, I've got fractions 2/5, 6/9,... I want to calculate the result of those fractions at compile-time and sort them later using that value at run-time.

Is this even possible?
Macros maybe?

**Edit:**
Thanks Naveen, but it doesn't answer the question if it's possible to calculate floats at compile time using templates. Using recursion, for example.

I can't find any info on the webs :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking. Do you mean something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

template <int a, int b> struct Fract {
    double value() const {
        const double f = a / double(b);
        return f;
    }
};

int main() {
    Fract <2,5> f;
    cout << f.value() << endl;
}
```

**Edit:** If you seriously want to get into template programming, meta or otherwise, I strongly suggest getting hold of the book [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/), which is excellent.

Comment: Template Meta Programming? That would be my guess.

Comment: Exactly, maybe I should have written it out :)

Comment: broken, you don't need to do this. You can just write 2.0/5 and the compiler will calculate it at compile time too.

Comment: @broken - I wouldn't bother testing it - I don't think this can be classed as meta-programming!

Comment: other than for pure fun or for learning purposes, is there any real use of this?

Comment: I read the question as an over-simplified version of the actual question, so the answer is necessarily over-simplified too. Obviously it was useful to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You don't require templates for that. Any decent compiler will optimize the calculations when you do something like this: `float f = 2.0/5;` BTW, if all are compile time variables why do you want to sort them at run time?

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some examples with template recursion](http://ubiety.uwaterloo.ca/~tveldhui/papers/Template-Metaprograms/meta-art.html).